# ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED Not Being called

Tags: android

When i am using windowmanger in order to display a floating action button and drag it to another button or view, i can't get it to react to "Drag entered", any ideas? i guess it's about the windowmanger but can't figure it out.

it seems like ACTION_DRAG_STARTED is working...

Code :

```
    WindowManager mWindowManager;

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
    params.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LOCAL_FOCUS_MODE;


    LinearLayout mLinearLayoutCloseArea = new LinearLayout(this);

    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    mWindowManager.addView(mLinearLayoutCloseArea, params);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    final FloatingActionButton fab3, fab4;
    layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.close_area_layout, mLinearLayoutCloseArea);

    fab3 = (FloatingActionButton) mLinearLayoutCloseArea.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton3);
    fab4 = (FloatingActionButton) mLinearLayoutCloseArea.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton4);


    fab3.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            fab3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");

            // Shadow For Drag event
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);

            // Version check for using Old and new Api
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {

                // New Api
                v.startDragAndDrop(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
            } else

                // Old Api
                v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
            return false;
        }
    });


            fab3.setOnDragListener(this);



    fab4.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    Log.d("Alive", " \n Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED ---- fab4");
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    Log.d("Alive", "\n\nAction is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED---- fab4");
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

sorry for my English, and thanks in advance.

Comment: set the same drag listener to both the views

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem.
Looks like it is expected to send true when receive ACTION_DRAG_STARTED action.

```
fab4.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                Log.d("Alive", " \n Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED ---- fab4");
                return true;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                Log.d("Alive", "\n\nAction is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED---- fab4");
                return false;
        }
    }
});
```

After that all other actions including ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED are successfully trigered.